# Is there a limit to the number of user entries in AllowUsers that can be given in sshd_config file in Linux?

Tags: linux, upgrade, openssh, sshd, amazon-linux

I have an SFTP server where I need to restrict users with specific IP addresses or ranges.

To achieve this, I had been appending `AllowUsers` entries to the `sshd_config` file like below and there are 180 such entries on the same line:

```
AllowUsers user1 user2 user3@ipaddress user4@ipaddress/n user5@ipaddres user5@address user5@address
```

and so on.

The problem is, the server's `ssh` service has been going down lately. And upon checking the server messages log, the error that causes the service failure is **Line 143 too long**. Line 143 is the `AllowUsers` line in my config file. The service seems to go down once the number of entries touches 184.

It seems like adding any more `AllowUsers` entries is not possible. Is there any kind of limit to the number of entries for `AllowUsers`?

**Please urgently help me out with a solution.** I don't think the `AllowGroups` is an option for me because I need to restrict each user with a different set of IPs.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov hey, no Artem, I had already seen it. I don't think the AllowGroups will solve my issue. If I do that then I will not be able to restrict individual users with different IP addresses I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to those who put up their inputs here :)

I upgraded my OpenSSH and the limit restriction mentioned in my question is no more an issue now.

I followed the below blogs to complete and troubleshoot my OpenSSH upgrade. I was doing it on Amazon Linux. However, I believe this should work on centos as well.

https://www.tecmint.com/install-openssh-server-from-source-in-linux/

https://blog.jonkimi.com/2020/04/17/Upgrade-openssh-server-on-Ubuntu/

http://blog.chinaunix.net/uid-28813320-id-5786956.html

Answer (score 2):

Looking through an older version of ssh, like [7.4](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/tree/V_7_4), we see that error message in `servconf.c` function [load_server_config](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_7_4/servconf.c#L1878), where the max line length is 4096 bytes.

However, looking at the handling of `AllowUsers` lines in the same file seems to suggest that you can simply add more lines of the same type. Eg

```
AllowUsers user4@ipaddress/n user5@ipaddress
AllowUsers user6@ipaddress/n user7@ipaddress
```

Note that the array to hold the entries has a fixed size of `MAX_ALLOW_USERS` i.e. 256 entries, in this version.
To get past that limit, you might be able to use `Match` lines to add more users.

Comment: Seems like OpenSSH_7.4p1 is the version used in this server. Is it possible for us to increase the 4096 bytes function load_server_config.

Comment: You would probably need to recompile from the sources, and you would still have the 256 entries limit. The earliest version to accept any line length seems to be 7.8, which also fixes the limit of 256 entries. You might be able to install a newer package from a future repository, but that's a separate question.

Comment: Alright,  thanks. Any idea if the 7.8 version has other major changes that might break my sftp connections somewhere. I also have mysecureshell in place to disable shell access for the users.

Comment: You'll have to peruse the [releasenotes](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html) for each revision downwards. They each have a helpful *Potentially-incompatible changes* section. As for mysecureshell, it says *No dependency on...OpenSSH version* so you should be ok.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to upgrade the openssh package from 7.4 to 7.8 safely.

Comment: I'm sorry I have no experience with amazon-linux. You should post a new question for that so others can answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading openssh-8.4p1 source code and I don't see any limits imposed on `AllowUsers`. Please try installing this version and report whether it's helped you or not. You can install it into `/usr/local` and make it listen on a different port, so that you don't need to mess with your old sshd.

Comment: It's a live SFTP server with jailed users and a lot of people connecting to them. I am worried that installing a newer version might break something on the somewere.

Comment: thanks, the newer version seem to not have the limit and the ssh service does not fail. I installed the 7.8 version from sourcecode. But the issue i face now is the service file doesnt not run sshd service after upgrade, however it works when i manually run just /usr/sbin/sshd in the terminal. Please let me know if you have any hints on this.